# How to discover and fill empty spaces between elements in isotope jquery grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

When resizing an element in isotope using perfectMasonry extention because of the variable sizes of the elements it creates some spaces.
I want to check with jquery every time there is a relayout if an empty space is created.
If it's created I want to insert a new element with size of the gap that is created between other elements to fill the space.

I tried using a background on a parent div of the container and with some css shadow-box to make it look nice but didnt make it. 
The code I am working on
 http://jsfiddle.net/TqVSs/
(could not link to perfectMasonry source from github so superMasonry is on the javascript box.Scroll down to find my code)

```
$('#container').isotope({
layoutMode: "perfectMasonry",
perfectMasonry: {
        columnWidth: 0,
        rowHeight: 125
}
})            



 $('#container').delegate( '.element', 'click', function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("dummy")==false){
            $(this).toggleClass('large');   
            $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co)!

Packery layouts are designed to fill gaps. Packery also has [great support for variable sizes](http://packery.metafizzy.co/options.html#element-sizing).

Answer (score 0):

I reordered after click events with settimeout function.
solution is below

```
  setTimeout(function(){
            $srid = $('.sonCalismalar .isler').packery({
                layoutMode: 'packery',
                itemSelector: '.element-item'
            });
            console.log("ok");
        },500);
```

full code is below

```
        $('.sonCalismalar nav').on('click', 'a', function () {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        // use filterFn if matches value
        // filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
        $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });

        //şimdi aktif 3. elementlerin margin rigth ını 0 yap
        //.urunler .element-item .ucunculer { margin-right: 0px; }        
        setTimeout(function(){
            $srid = $('.sonCalismalar .isler').packery({
                layoutMode: 'packery',
                itemSelector: '.element-item'
            });
            console.log("ok");
        },500); 

    });
```